# Using a function in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a global function that I've set and tested to make sure it's working:

```
function shortenUrl(url) { 
   ...
}
```

Then I'm trying to call that function in a variable in another function like this:

```
var pageLink = $(location).attr('href'),
    shortLink = shortenUrl(pageLink);
```

So when I try to run this I get an undefined error. However if I change the the pageLink variable from finding the page url with jQuery to something hard coded like "http://example.com" and console.log the value in the global function I'll get a shorten linked returned.

I'm just commenting out the return call like this:

```
//return shortUrl;
console.log(shortUrl);
```

That's giving me the correct value in the console. But it's not getting returned back to my shortLink variable because that still shows up as undefined. Am I missing something simple here? Why isn't the value returning to the shortLink variable and why does the link that's dynamically created with jQuery pass through the function?

UPDATE edit:

Okay to reset this just a little bit. I think the problem lays within the shortenUrl function or how I'm passing values to it. Just to test the function I did this:

```
    function shortenUrl(url) {

        var url = url,
            username = 'username',
            key = 'api key';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten',
            data: {
                longUrl: url,
                apiKey: key,
                login: username
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (v) {
                var shortUrl = v.data.url;
                return shortUrl;
                //console.log(shortUrl);
            }
        });
    }

var shorten = shortenUrl('http://google.com');
console.log(shorten);
```

Console.log(shorten) returns undefined. However if I uncomment the console.log(shortUrl); and comment out return shortUrl; within the function I get a correctly shorten URL returned from bit.ly.

Why wouldn't I get the correct shortened url returned at the console.log(shorten)? Is the variable being passed wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be `console.log(shortLink);`?

Comment: are you running initialization (`pageLink=...`) on document.ready?

Comment: Could you post the shortenUrl code? I think you might not return the value, or something like that.

Comment: Does your code run on DOM ready? it could be that there is a race condition and $(location) is not defined yet because the DOM is not loaded yet so shortenUrl doesn't get a value sent to it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a return url in your `shortenUrl` function, which returns your shortened url, like this:

```
function shortenUrl(url) {
   var shortUrl = url; // for the sake of simplicity
   return shortUrl;
}
```

I am curious if my tip was ok, please let us all know.

**UPDATE**:

```
$(window).load(function(){
function shortenUrl(url) {

    var url = url,
        username = 'bit.ly username',
        key = 'api Key';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten',
        data: {
            longUrl: url,
            apiKey: key,
            login: username
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(v) {
            var shortUrl = v.data.url;
            return shortUrl;
        }
    });
}

function some() {
    var pageLink = $(location).attr('href'),
        shortenLink = shortenUrl(pageLink);

    var link = $('<a href="' + shortenLink + '">Shorten Link</a>');
    link.prependTo('element');
}
});
```

I cannot try the code, due to missing key and username, but this should work. Make sure you replace both with the correct ones and that you call your code, like this:

```
some();
```

And always watch the browser's console for errors/warnings!

Comment: Didn't fix it here is a jsfiddle of the basic idea of how the code is running it's includes the full shortenUrl function.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to make it public try this one - http://jsfiddle.net/erikakers/zZCEA/

Comment: I edited my answer, corrected your code a bit -- you had two things there: first, missing plus, second missing function name in function declaration.

Comment: I don't think that was it. Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/erikakers/zZCEA/ I'm getting undefined return on the shortedLink variable and that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Of course you are, the jsonp response that you get from the shortener service has http 500 error, because you are sending wrong api key and username and your shortenUrl never gets into the success part of the ajax response. Correct those, as I said in my updated post and it should work.

Comment: When I console.log within that shortenUrl function I'm getting an correct bit.ly shorten url back. Could it be that it's not returning the value correctly out of the function? Because if I try to console.log the value outside of the shortenUrl function I'm getting an undefined error.

Comment: If after this line var shortUrl = v.data.url; console.log(shortUrl); shows the correct url, then all you need is a return shortUrl; right after that and it should work.

Comment: You can't return a value from an asynchronous ajax "success" handler like that. It makes no sense, and this will therefore not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't have much experience with `jsonp` but ajax call should return the [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). If `shortenUrl` function returned that promise then in the caller you can use `done` like this:

```
    function shortenUrl(url) {

        var url = url,
            username = 'bit.ly username',
            key = 'api Key';

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten',
            data: {
                longUrl: url,
                apiKey: key,
                login: username
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }

    function modifyDom(v) {
        var shortUrl = v.data.url,
            link = $('<a href="' + shortenLink '">Shorten Link</a>');
        link.prependTo('element');
    }    

    $( function() {
        var pageLink = $(location).attr('href');
        shortenUrl(pageLink)
            .done( modifyDom },
    }​ );
```

Although this code is not tested, I hope you will get the idea.